# Forcing footer to stay under last cell in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, footer

I have a tableview with custom cells. What I want is to have a footer (like a "loading" indicator") at the bottom of the tableview. I am using this code to add the footer:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);

    return spinner;
}
```

But this makes the footer "float" over the bottom of the tableview and overlaps the bottom of the table:

[image]

How can I force the footer to only be visible **under the last cell of the table**? Like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set tableFooterView instead of setting section footer views.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the storyboard by dragging a UIView into UITableView, and place your loading indicator there .
From your document outline should looks similar to this
[image]